# YouTube Green Screen in Brave Browser

Tags: youtube, brave

Since a few days I am experiencing a Green Screen phenomena with YouTube and Brave Browser. All I see is a green screen. I hear the sound perfectly, and if I play the video in another browser it just works fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxyQq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube Help article
[Green screen in video player](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1230977?hl=en)
has these points of advice:

- Try another browser. If this helps, then the problem is specific to your browser.
- Turn off hardware acceleration in your browser
- Update your graphics driver.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be useful.